# as3 load picture from xml file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

please can someone help me!? I am loading data from an `xml` file with `FLASH`, everything is working fine except for displaying a picture from a link in the `xml` file. The `xml` file has `whitespaces`. I've fixed the problem for text but the picture is still not showing because of the `whitespaces` in the xml file.

Please can anyone help me?/??`

Comment: Can you please add a small sample of your XML, and the ActionScript you've written to load it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `ignoreWhitespace` property. Why would you have whitespaces in an `URL` anyways??

[Adobe help - ignoreWhitespace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#ignoreWhitespace)

Also some code and the xml would help

Comment: I'm doing banner it's retrieving data from xml file, so it's displaying picture from link in XML File but the file contains white spaces, and the website that am putting the Banner on their website is stupid they are telling me we can't solve white spaces fix it from the flash file :(

Comment: look at the link i postet!! set ignoreWhitespace to true!!

Comment: You need to provide some code!! How are u loading the pic? Show a sample of the xml file! Nobody can mindread here ;)

Comment: am showing the picture in movieclip, and here is sample of xml :

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ads>
    <ad>
        <price>
            110000.00
        </price>
        <ad_url>
            http://domain/classified/autos4x4s/porsche/carrera/2013/2/16/997-carrera-s-2/?hsssdfvbcb=1
        </ad_url>
        <year>
            2005
        </year>
        <model>
            Carrera / 911
        </model>
        <photo_url>
            http://domain/images/user_images/2013/02/16/17739987_CP_photo.jpeg
        </photo_url>
        <id>
            11251161
        </id>
        <manufacturer>
            Porsche
        </manufacturer>
    </ad>
</ads>

Comment: it's having white spaces :(

Comment: Accept edit, so others can see clean formatted xml!
And show the AS3 code where u handle the xml and try to load the pic!